# Partition Permissions - chgrp cannot access

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount

I have a partition on a hard drive with the label 'Big Drive' (see sda5 below)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0005a7c8

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048  117114879  117112832  55.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        117116926 1953523711 1836406786 875.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        117116928 1943300095 1826183168 870.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1943302144 1953523711   10221568   4.9G 82 Linux swap /Solaris
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000735db

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 960122879 960120832 457.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3       960124926 976771071  16646146     8G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       960124928 976771071  16646144     8G 82 Linux swap /Solaris

nevil@Desktop:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="00d44d08-7c27-42d5-bb2b-0e54507b5e93" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="0005a7c8-01"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Big Drive" UUID="f455fc36-19b4-4c1d-9923-9f2b5bb7d406" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0005a7c8-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="93e8651c-da16-43c1-ab3e-3e6d910d1085" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0005a7c8-06"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="04f7f55d-0867-4de1-8312-a20a4c5db165" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000735db-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="bec981a2-858e-4821-8c90-b22d1ac1cfd8" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000735db-05"
```

It is owned by Root. I am the administrator (Ubuntu 16.04) and there are four other users. The partition contains document files. I want everyone to be able to read/write to these folders. However, I am put off using 'chown 777' command (as everyone says it's so dangerous!) so tried following instructions to add ownership to a group. However this has been unsuccessful. Every time I try to use 'chgrp' command, it fails to see the partition or tells me it doesn't exist:

```
nevil@Desktop:~$ ll /media/nevil
total 16
drwxr-x---+  4 root root 4096 Jan  5 15:49 ./
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jan  4 21:20 ../
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4096 Jan  4 20:51 00d44d08-7c27-42d5-bb2b-0e54507b5e93/
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4096 Apr 12  2016 Big Drive/

nevil@Desktop:~$ sudo chgrp adm /media/nevil/Big Drive
chgrp: cannot access '/media/nevil/Big': No such file or directory
chgrp: cannot access 'Drive': No such file or directory
```

(I also tried it using the UUID, with the same result).
Can anyone help? I've tried it with the partition mounted and unmounted.

Thanks
Nevil

Comment: I am not knowledgable on group access, but with Linux best not to use spaces. Your commands when you have spaces must be escaped or quoted. Better to use underscore Big_Drive, one name BigDrive or camel case (which is same in this example BigDrive.

Answer (score 0):

A space is a dilimiter (seperates arguments). You have to enclose the drive name in quotes. try:

```
sudo chgrp adm /media/nevil/'Big Drive'
```